# What is the mount that Thranduil is on when he arrives in "The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey?"

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, movie, the-hobbit

As shown here:
[image: Thranduil, with elves on foot behind him, sits mounted on a large, somewhat shaggy-coated quadruped with a horse-like face, deer-like ears and strange antlers that have the thickness of a moose's but the spikiness of a deer's]

What is this creature?

Comment: Video game questions are out of our scope. We can tell you about the creature Thranduil is riding, but you'll find [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/) more helpful for questions about LotR Online. (Lothlórien is a forest. Thranduil is the elven king played by Lee Pace.)

Comment: Absolutely non-authoritative answer: an [Irish Elk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_elk)

Comment: @NiallC. I don't think it's ever specified in the book exactly what Thranduil rode, only that he did ride, so that's probably the best answer.

Comment: @BESW What the... The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey is a _movie_. That strange elk is shown in the movie. What videogame are you talking about? :P

Comment: @AndresF. Check the edit history.

Comment: @BESW Oh, I see. Sorry! :)

Comment: It's a moose! The Elves must be Canadian!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### [*Megaloceros*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megaloceros), the Giant Elk.

These are an extinct real-world creature, and [there's no reference to them in any of the books](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Megaloceros). Thranduil is only said to have ridden... something... and so the film producers chose a cool visual appropriate to the Woodland Realm.

Comment: Ironic, there is a theory that Giant Elk extinction was caused by their moor like habitat becoming more wooded.